# How to have Powershell Script output in a single line and separated by ;

Tags: powershell, text-files

I'm not able to do that, I just want the output .txt with one line and each output followed by `;`

```powershell
New-Item C:\temp\test.txt
Set-Content C:\temp\test.txt (Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | Foreach {"{0:N2}" -f ([math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))}) 
Add-Content C:\temp\test.txt (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor).name 
Add-Content C:\temp\test.txt (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption 
Add-Content C:\temp\test.txt (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController).name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the outputs to an array and use [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#split-and-join-operators) to write the array elements with custom separator

```
mkdir C:\temp
@((Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | Foreach {"{0:N2}" -f ([math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))}),
  (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor).name,
  (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption,
  (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController).name
) -join ';' > C:\temp\test.txt
```

Note that `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController` will return information for all GPUs in the system, so if you have multiple GPUs (for example hybrid graphics systems) then it'll print multiple lines instead of one. So you may need to use `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController).name -join ','` instead, or `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController)[0].name` if you just want the first graphics card

I guess the same thing happens in `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor` if there are multiple physical CPUs in the system

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the `-NoNewLine` switch for both, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.2) and [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.2) combined with string concatenation following what you already have:

```sh
$file = New-Item test.txt
Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory |
    Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum |
    ForEach-Object {"{0:N2}" -f ([math]::Round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))} |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $file -NoNewline
';' + (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor).Name | Add-Content -LiteralPath $file -NoNewline
';' + (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption | Add-Content -LiteralPath $file -NoNewline
';' + (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController).Name | Add-Content -LiteralPath $file
```

However, it's worth noting that it would be a lot easier to just concatenate all output from the cmdlets in memory and output to the file just once, for this example we can use the [`-f` format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f):

```sh
$file = New-Item test.txt
'{0:N2};{1};{2};{3}' -f 
    [math]::Round((((Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory).Capacity | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 1Gb), 2),
    (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor).Name,
    (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption,
    (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController).Name | Set-Content -LiteralPath $file
```